# AngularJS app sign-in function 404 error, xhr.send(post || null)

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gulp

An old web app that uses Angular, gulp and coffee-script, and was running whit forever(NPM package).

When I click the sign-in button [on the page](https://dashboard.pcbu.co.nz), the page will refresh and show a 404 error, an apache access log saying

> "POST /api/user/sign-in HTTP/1.1" 404 488 "http://localhost/sign-in" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

Need help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

We didn't change any code or env, only use Nginx Proxy manager to take the place of Kemp load balancer.

I got the apache log because I copied all stuff and the database running it on localhost.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please edit your question if you need to provide more context. Also, please redact sensitive information from the logs and attach them to your question